# MATLAB date selection popup calendar for gui

Tags: user-interface, matlab, calendar, datepicker

Does anyone know of a method to display a popup date selection calendar in a MATLAB gui? I know the financial toolbox has a `uicalendar` function, but unfortunately I don't have that toolbox.

I have a hunch I'm going to have to use some Java or some other language for this one, which I know nothing about.

I'm looking for something similar to this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [welie.com](http://www.welie.com/patterns/images/date-selector-expedia-small.png))</sub>

which would return a date string after the user selects the date.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'll decide which one to accept when I get around to testing the various approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have much time for a more complete answer, unfortunately, but I'd try `uitable` to create a table and to define the `CellSelectionCallback` to get the date.

Here's a bit to get you started:

```
dates = calendar;
dates(~any(dates,2),:) = [];
fh = figure;
uh = uitable('parent',fh,'data',dates,'ColumnWidth',repmat({20},1,7),...
             'ColumnName',{'S','M','T','W','T','F','S'});
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are two approaches that would give you a professional-looking calendar component in Matlab without too much programming work:

1. Use a **Java** calendar component (for example, one of [these](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Calendar-Date-Time.htm) or [these](http://www.google.com/search?q=swing+calendar)). Once you download the relevant Java class or Jar-file, add it to your static Java classpath (use the `edit('classpath.txt')` command from the Matlab Command Prompt). Finally, use the built-in ***javacomponent*** function to place the component in your Matlab figure window.
2. If you are using a Windows OS, you can embed any **Active-X** calendar control that is available. Use the built-in ***actxcontrolselect*** function to choose your favorite calendar control (for example, Microsoft Office's "Calendar Control 11.0" - MSCAL.Calendar.7 - which is automatically installed with Office 2003; or "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0" - MSComCtl2.DTPicker.2, or ...). Then use the ***actxcontrol*** function to place the component in your Matlab figure window.
3. Matlab has some pretty useful built-in calendar (date-selection) controls - I posted [an article about them](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/date-selection-components/) today

Comment: @Yair Altman : Javacomponent seems to be undocumented. Being completely unfamiliar with using java in MATLAB, could explain the input parameters?

Answer (score 4):

I'd start with the [calendar() function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/calendar.html) which outputs a matrix containing the calendar for any month. I assume you could combine this with a user-clickable interface to retrieve a specific date?

The following code is really ugly, but could help you get started...

```
 WINDOW_WIDTH = 300;
 WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;
f= figure('Position',[300 300 WINDOW_WIDTH WINDOW_HEIGHT]);

 NB_ROWS = 6;
 NB_COLS = 7;
 width = round(WINDOW_WIDTH/NB_COLS);
 height = round(WINDOW_HEIGHT/NB_ROWS);
 buttons = nan(NB_ROWS,NB_COLS);
 dates = calendar();

 for row = 1:NB_ROWS
    for col = 1:NB_COLS
       if dates(row,col) == 0
          mydate = '';
       else
          mydate = sprintf('%i', dates(row,col));
       end
       buttons(row,col) = uicontrol('Style', 'PushButton', ...
          'String', mydate, ...
          'Position', [(col-1)*width (NB_ROWS - row)*height width height]);
    end
 end
```

Comment: You can insert `dates(all(dates==0,2),:)=[];` after calendar() call to eliminate the row with all zeros.

Comment: And `[NB_ROWS,NB_COLS] = size(dates);`

Comment: Good points. I'm a bit busy today, but feel free to edit accordingly :)

Comment: Your solution is much prettier than using uitable, but I think uitable will be much less messy to deal with.