# Calendar gui for Matlab Guide

Tags: user-interface, matlab, date, matlab-guide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB date selection popup calendar for gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655554/matlab-date-selection-popup-calendar-for-gui)

Does anyone know of a Calendar GUI for matlab's Guide gui system?  I'd like to implement an easy user clickable date selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate [MATLAB date selection popup calendar for gui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655554/matlab-date-selection-popup-calendar-for-gui)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did search, obviously not hard enough.  Plenty of ideas there.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily integrate several built-in date-selection (calendar) components in your Matlab GUI: 
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/date-selection-components/

You will need to place the relevant code in the *_OutputFcn() function within your GUIDE-generated m-file

Yair Altman 
http://UndocumentedMatlab.com

Comment: Thanks Yair, I'm a keen reader of your blog and found the section you mention.  Keep it up!